# "Dashboard component order" in the mobile app and email subscriptions are messed up

Tags: email, mobile, configuration, dashboard, salesforce-mobile-app

If you have a dashboard with 9 components which are arranged like this **on the desktop:**

```
1   2   3
4   5   6
7   8   9
```

... then obviously, the reader reads the screen in a left-to-right order, like this:

```
1 → 2 → 3 → 4 → 5 → 6 → 7 → 8 → 9.
```

However, it shows up on the **mobile app** as well as in **email subscriptions** in a **top-down order**, **which completely messes up the experience**, like this:

```
1
4
7
2
5
8
3
6
9
```

**How can this be rectified?**

The desired order in mobile app as well as in email subscriptions is obviously:

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is to have 2 dashboards:

Dashboard for desktop:  
1   2   3  
4   5   6  
7   8   9

Dashboard for mobile and email subscriptions:  
1  
2  
3  
4  
5  
6  
7  
8  
9